# Converting control characters to graphical in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, binary, control-characters

I need a PHP code that would convert control characters to graphical (like U+0000 to ␀ (U+2400)). Unicode 0000-001F should be replaced with unicode 2400-241F. I am writing a PHP code that would show the contents of the file.

Comment: @Leigh I don't know what I should try lol.

Comment: What are the Unicode values of the characters you want to replace? What **exactly** do you want to replace them with?

Comment: have you tried `str_replace(chr(0), '␀', $yourText)`?

Comment: @Gordon I don't think is useful. I would need to do that for every character. For Jocelyn, those characters in unicode 0000-001F should be replaced with unicode 2400-241F